# Recoger x muestras de x simulaciones

Tags: python, python-2.7

El siguiente código genera un CSV en el que se muestran una serie de columnas (JUGADOR, SENAL, RONDA1, RONDA2, RONDA3). En las columnas "RONDAx" aparecen las veces que cada jugador ha mostrado una señal determinada en cada ronda a lo largo de 1000 simulaciones del juego (ver `for _ in range(1000)`). El código está configurado para 3 rondas y 4 jugadores.

```
from random import random, sample
from bisect import bisect
import csv

class Partida():
    def __init__(self, jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, s, b, x, m):
        self.emparejamientos = emparejamientos
        self.senales = senales
        self.s = s
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.m = m
        self.jugadores = {nombre: Partida.Jugador(senales)
                            for pareja in emparejamientos[0]
                                for nombre in pareja}
        self.memoria = list()


    def generar_senales(self):

        def with_b(muestra, observa, s, r):
            if not (muestra == observa == 0):
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra/r) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (self.x) * observa/r) + ((0.98) * self.b * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            else:
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra/r) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (self.x) * observa/r) + ((0.98) * 0 * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            return result

        def choice(opciones, probs):
            probAcumuladas = list()
            aux = 0
            for p in probs:
                aux += p
                probAcumuladas.append(aux)
            r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
            op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
            return opciones[op]

        yield dict(zip(self.jugadores.keys(), self.senales))


        r = 1
        while True:
            eleccs = dict.fromkeys(self.jugadores.keys())
            for nombre, inst in self.jugadores.items():
                probs = [with_b(inst.mem_mostradas[op], inst.men_observadas[op], self.s[indx], r)
                            for indx, op in enumerate(self.senales)]
                eleccs[nombre] = choice(self.senales, probs)
            r += 1
            yield eleccs


    def jugar(self):
        gen_sens =  self.generar_senales()
        for n, ronda in enumerate(self.emparejamientos):
            senales = next(gen_sens)
            self.memoria.append(senales)

            for jugador1, jugador2 in ronda:
                self.jugadores[jugador1].men_observadas[senales[jugador2]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].men_observadas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador1].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador2]] += 1


    class Jugador():
        def __init__(self, senales):
            self.mem_mostradas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
            self.men_observadas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}



def main():
    jugadores = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    senales = ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', ]
    emparejamientos = [[(1,2),(3,4)],
                       [(1,3),(2,4)],
                       [(1,4),(2,3)]]
    s=[1,0,0,0]
    b=0.5
    x=0.5
    m=0.02

    rondas = ['RONDA' + str(n+1) for n in range(len(emparejamientos))]
    estadisticas = {jugador:{senal:[0 for ronda in rondas]
                        for senal in senales}
                            for jugador in jugadores}

    for _ in range(1000):
        juego = Partida(jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, s, b, x, m)
        juego.jugar()
        for n, ronda in enumerate(juego.memoria):
            for jugador, senal in ronda.items():
                estadisticas[jugador][senal][n] += 1

    with open('salida.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        writer =csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                    quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        writer.writerow(['JUGADOR', 'SENAL'] + rondas)

        for jugador in jugadores:
            for senal in senales:
                writer.writerow([jugador, senal]+estadisticas[jugador][senal])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Se desea ahora utilizar este mismo código para generar x muestras de x simulaciones y recoger los datos en un CSV como en el siguiente ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, tal y como se muestra, se persigue que el código realice 3 veces 1000 simulaciones del juego completo, y que los resultados de las 3 veces (3 muestras) se almacenen tal y como se muestra en la imagen. Donde en "muestra" el número "1" hace referencia a las primeras 1000 simulaciones, "2" hace referencia a las segundas 1000 simulaciones y así sucesivamente. Donde "ronda" hace referencia al número de ronda dentro del juego. Donde "jugador" hace referencia al número de jugador.

Nótese que en este caso se incluyen los parámetros b, x y m en la tabla, y que los números en las columnas "Senalx" deben hacer referencia a las veces que cada señal ha sido elegida en cada ronda.

Comment: ¿Todas las muestras van a tener los mismos parámetros, incluyendo `b`, `x` y `m`? Es decir, ¿tódos los parámetros son identicos para las x muestras de x simulaciones cada una?

Comment: @FJSevilla Sí, los parámetros, en este caso, son idénticos para las x muestras de x simulaciones. No obstante, si podemos, sería interesante tener la opción de poder decidir si "correr" el código completo (x muestras de x simulaciones) con valores fijos (e.g. b=0.0, x=0.5) o para una lista de valores. Los valores del modelo matemático para b y x varían entre 0.0 y 1.0. b = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0] y x=  [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]. El valor de m, que representa algo así como mutación, puede quedarse fijo en 0.02.

Comment: @FJSevilla, he intentado hacer lo anterior declarando una lista para b y x y añadiendo un for en la función main. Pero parece que esto choca con la función with_b. Tener la opción de alternar con valores fijos y listas al definir las variables b y x sería perfecto.

Comment: ¿Quieres poder variar los valores de b y x para cada simulación dentro de una muestra o para cada muestra de 1000 simulaciones? Creo que es lo segundo, es decir para tres muestras tendrias 3 valores de  x, 3 de b y 3 de m (uno para cada muestra) ¿Es esto?

Comment: @FJSevilla, entiendo lo que has hecho. Vaya facilidad que tienes, qué envidia, a mí me lleva días. Creo que estaría bien, en efecto, que cada muestra se ejecutase con una combinación posible para los valores de b y x diferente. En un ejemplo sencillo, por ejemplo, definiendo dos listas de posibles valores b=[0.0, 1.0] y x=[0.5, 0.6]. Si en el futuro se desea mantener el valor constante de un parámetro en todas las muestras tan solo habría que hacer b=[0.0, 0.0] por ejemplo, ¿no?

Comment: Tienes varias opciones, pero creo qque sería más legible pasar las muestras como una lista de diccionarios donde las claves son los parámetros b, x y m. Voy a actualizar la respuesta a ver que te parece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haciendo algunas modificaciones en la función `main()` puedes conseguir lo que quieres (si te he entendido bién). Simplemente modificamos la estructura de `estadisticas` para que almacene también la variable `muestra` y posteriormente creamos el `csv` con la estructura deseada usando estos datos:

```
from random import random, sample
from bisect import bisect
import csv

class Partida():
    def __init__(self, jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, s, b, x, m):
        self.emparejamientos = emparejamientos
        self.senales = senales
        self.s = s
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.m = m
        self.jugadores = {nombre: Partida.Jugador(senales)
                            for pareja in emparejamientos[0]
                                for nombre in pareja}
        self.memoria = list()


    def generar_senales(self):

        def with_b(muestra, observa, s, r):
            if not (muestra == observa == 0):
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra/r) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (self.x) * observa/r) + ((0.98) * self.b * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            else:
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra/r) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (self.x) * observa/r) + ((0.98) * 0 * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            return result

        def choice(opciones, probs):
            probAcumuladas = list()
            aux = 0
            for p in probs:
                aux += p
                probAcumuladas.append(aux)
            r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
            op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
            return opciones[op]

        yield dict(zip(self.jugadores.keys(), self.senales))


        r = 1
        while True:
            eleccs = dict.fromkeys(self.jugadores.keys())
            for nombre, inst in self.jugadores.items():
                probs = [with_b(inst.mem_mostradas[op], inst.men_observadas[op], self.s[indx], r)
                            for indx, op in enumerate(self.senales)]
                eleccs[nombre] = choice(self.senales, probs)
            r += 1
            yield eleccs


    def jugar(self):
        gen_sens =  self.generar_senales()
        for n, ronda in enumerate(self.emparejamientos):
            senales = next(gen_sens)
            self.memoria.append(senales)

            for jugador1, jugador2 in ronda:
                self.jugadores[jugador1].men_observadas[senales[jugador2]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].men_observadas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador1].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador2]] += 1


    class Jugador():
        def __init__(self, senales):
            self.mem_mostradas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
            self.men_observadas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}



def main():
    jugadores = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    senales = ['Senal 1', 'Senal 2', 'Senal 3', 'Senal 4']
    emparejamientos = [[(1,2),(3,4)],
                       [(1,3),(2,4)],
                       [(1,4),(2,3)]]
    s=[1,0,0,0]
    b=0.5
    x=0.5
    m=0.02

    muestras = 3
    simulaciones = 1000

    estadisticas = {jugador:{muestra:{senal:[0 for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos)+1)]
                        for senal in senales}
                            for muestra in range(1, muestras + 1)}
                                for jugador in jugadores}


    for muestra in range(1, muestras+1):
        for _ in range(simulaciones):
            juego = Partida(jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, s, b, x, m)
            juego.jugar()
            for n, ronda in enumerate(juego.memoria):
                for jugador, senal in ronda.items():
                    estadisticas[jugador][muestra][senal][n] += 1

        with open('salida.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
            writer =csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                        quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            writer.writerow(['Muestra' ,'Jugador', 'Ronda', 'b', 'x', 'm'] + senales)

            for jugador in jugadores:
                for muestra in range(1, muestras+1):
                    for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos)+1):
                        aux = [estadisticas[jugador][muestra][senal][ronda-1] for senal in senales]
                        writer.writerow([muestra, jugador, ronda, b, x, m]+aux)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Esto nos genera un `csv` de la forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Edición:**

Si quieres poder pasarle a cada muestra distintos valores de `b`, `x` y `m` puedes crear una lista con las rondas y pasar cada conjunto de parámetros dentro de una lista, o mejor dentro de un diccionario. Por ejemplo, si tenemos tres rondas, podemos pasar los valores así:

```
muestras = [{'b':0.2, 'x':0.5, 'm':0.02},
            {'b':0.4, 'x':0.6, 'm':0.02},
            {'b':0.5, 'x':0.7, 'm':0.02}]
```

Si en un momento dado quieres que todos los parámetros sean iguales puedes hacer algo como:

```
muestras = [{'b':0.2, 'x':0.5, 'm':0.02} for _ in range(3)]
```

Lo cual crearía 3 rondas y todas tienen como valores de `b`, `x` y `m` 0.2,0.5 y 0.02 respectivamente.

El código podría quedar así:

```
from random import random, sample
from bisect import bisect
import csv

class Partida():
    def __init__(self, jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, s, b, x, m):
        self.emparejamientos = emparejamientos
        self.senales = senales
        self.s = s
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.m = m
        self.jugadores = {nombre: Partida.Jugador(senales)
                            for pareja in emparejamientos[0]
                                for nombre in pareja}
        self.memoria = list()


    def generar_senales(self):

        def with_b(muestra, observa, s, r):
            if not (muestra == observa == 0):
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra/r) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (self.x) * observa/r) + ((0.98) * self.b * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            else:
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra/r) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (self.x) * observa/r) + ((0.98) * 0 * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            return result

        def choice(opciones, probs):
            probAcumuladas = list()
            aux = 0
            for p in probs:
                aux += p
                probAcumuladas.append(aux)
            r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
            op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
            return opciones[op]

        yield dict(zip(self.jugadores.keys(), self.senales))


        r = 1
        while True:
            eleccs = dict.fromkeys(self.jugadores.keys())
            for nombre, inst in self.jugadores.items():
                probs = [with_b(inst.mem_mostradas[op], inst.men_observadas[op], self.s[indx], r)
                            for indx, op in enumerate(self.senales)]
                eleccs[nombre] = choice(self.senales, probs)
            r += 1
            yield eleccs


    def jugar(self):
        gen_sens =  self.generar_senales()
        for n, ronda in enumerate(self.emparejamientos):
            senales = next(gen_sens)
            self.memoria.append(senales)

            for jugador1, jugador2 in ronda:
                self.jugadores[jugador1].men_observadas[senales[jugador2]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].men_observadas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador1].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador2]] += 1


    class Jugador():
        def __init__(self, senales):
            self.mem_mostradas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
            self.men_observadas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}



def main():
    jugadores = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    senales = ['Senal 1', 'Senal 2', 'Senal 3', 'Senal 4']
    emparejamientos = [[(1,2),(3,4)],
                       [(1,3),(2,4)],
                       [(1,4),(2,3)]]
    s=[1,0,0,0]

    muestras = [{'b':0.2, 'x':0.5, 'm':0.02},
                {'b':0.4, 'x':0.6, 'm':0.02},
                {'b':0.5, 'x':0.7, 'm':0.02}]


    simulaciones = 1000
    estadisticas = {jugador:{muestra:{senal:[0 for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos)+1)]
                        for senal in senales}
                            for muestra in range(len(muestras))}
                                for jugador in jugadores}


    for mu in range(len(muestras)):
        for _ in range(simulaciones):
            juego = Partida(jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, s, muestras[mu]['b'],muestras[mu]['x'], muestras[mu]['m'])
            juego.jugar()
            for n, ronda in enumerate(juego.memoria):
                for jugador, senal in ronda.items():
                    estadisticas[jugador][mu][senal][n] += 1

        with open('salidav4.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
            writer =csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                        quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            writer.writerow(['Muestra' ,'Jugador', 'Ronda', 'b', 'x', 'm'] + senales)

            for jugador in jugadores:
                for mu in range(len(muestras)):
                    for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos)+1):
                        aux = [estadisticas[jugador][mu][senal][ronda-1] for senal in senales]
                        writer.writerow([mu+1, jugador, ronda, muestras[mu]['b'], muestras[mu]['x'], muestras[mu]['m']]+aux)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Lo que nos genera algo como:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que es lo que deseas pero revisalo por si acaso.

Comment: la respuesta es excepcional, como siempre. Esto nos da muchas posibilidades para generar muestras y jugar con los parámetros. Tener varias muestras permite obtener distribuciones normales que comparar estadísticamente. Veo que has ido tocando solo la función main (de manera magistral eso sí). Imagino que si deseamos a su vez obtener 3 muestras de cada diccionario de parámetros, tan solo hay que añadir [for in range (3)] tras cada diccionario. La verdad que me estás ayudando mucho y estoy aprendiendo un montón contigo.

Comment: Si solo se ha retocado la función main (la clase Partida no hay que modificarla dada la flexibilidad que nos brinda la POO). Si quieres obtener 3 muestras de cada conjunto de parámetros puedes hacer: `muestras = [{'b':0.2, 'x':0.5, 'm':0.02},
                {'b':0.4, 'x':0.6, 'm':0.02},
                {'b':0.5, 'x':0.7, 'm':0.02}]`
`muestras = [d for d in muestras for _ in range(3)]` O lo siguiente: `muestras = [{'b':0.2, 'x':0.5, 'm':0.02},
                {'b':0.4, 'x':0.6, 'm':0.02},
                {'b':0.5, 'x':0.7, 'm':0.02}]*3`

Comment: he implementado la posibilidad de realizar simulaciones con diferentes combinaciones de la variable s. ¿Puedes echarle un ojo para ver si es correcto lo que he hecho? Creo que en este punto eres el único que entiende la locura en que andamos metidos :)

Answer (score 0):

Tomando la última versión del código, he estado implementando una nueva posibilidad. Se habrá observado que la variable s (que hace referencia a algo así como al valor intrínseco de cada señal y que es tenido en cuenta en la ecuación al calcular la probabilidad con que cada señal será elegida en la siguiente generación), hasta ahora venía declarándose como una lista fija:

```
s= [1,0,0,0] #El valor de la "señal 1" es 1, de la "señal 2" 0, de la "señal 3" 0 y de la "señal 4" 0.
```

Bien, pues he implementado la posibilidad de que los valores de las señales se puedan alternar y podamos realizar x simulaciones para cada combinación de valores intrínsecos de s. He tocado solo la función `_init_` y la función `def main()`, para obtener un CSV con la impresión de los resultados.

Aquí está el código:

```
from random import random, sample
from bisect import bisect
import csv

class Partida():
    def __init__(self, jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, s1,s2,s3,s4, b, x, m):
        self.emparejamientos = emparejamientos
        self.senales = senales
        self.s = [s1,s2,s3,s4]
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.m = m
        self.jugadores = {nombre: Partida.Jugador(senales)
                            for pareja in emparejamientos[0]
                                for nombre in pareja}
        self.memoria = list()


    def generar_senales(self):

        def with_b(muestra, observa, s, r):
            if not (muestra == observa == 0):
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra/r) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (self.x) * observa/r) + ((0.98) * self.b * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            else:
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra/r) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (self.x) * observa/r) + ((0.98) * 0 * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            return result

        def choice(opciones, probs):
            probAcumuladas = list()
            aux = 0
            for p in probs:
                aux += p
                probAcumuladas.append(aux)
            r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
            op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
            return opciones[op]

        yield dict(zip(self.jugadores.keys(), self.senales))


        r = 1
        while True:
            eleccs = dict.fromkeys(self.jugadores.keys())
            for nombre, inst in self.jugadores.items():
                probs = [with_b(inst.mem_mostradas[op], inst.men_observadas[op], self.s[indx], r)
                            for indx, op in enumerate(self.senales)]
                eleccs[nombre] = choice(self.senales, probs)
            r += 1
            yield eleccs


    def jugar(self):
        gen_sens =  self.generar_senales()
        for n, ronda in enumerate(self.emparejamientos):
            senales = next(gen_sens)
            self.memoria.append(senales)

            for jugador1, jugador2 in ronda:
                self.jugadores[jugador1].men_observadas[senales[jugador2]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].men_observadas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador1].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador2]] += 1


    class Jugador():
        def __init__(self, senales):
            self.mem_mostradas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
            self.men_observadas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}



def main():
    jugadores = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    senales = ['Senal 1', 'Senal 2', 'Senal 3', 'Senal 4']
    emparejamientos = [[(1, 2), (3, 4)],
                       [(1, 3), (2, 4)],
                       [(1, 4), (2, 3)]]

    patron=1
    sm = [{'s1': 1, 's2': 0, 's3': 0, 's4': 0},
         {'s1': 0, 's2': 1, 's3': 0, 's4': 0},
         {'s1': 0, 's2': 0, 's3': 1, 's4': 0},
         {'s1': 0, 's2': 0, 's3': 0, 's4': 1}]
    sm = [d for d in sm for _ in range (10)]

    muestras = [{'b': 0.0, 'x': 0.0, 'm': 0.02},
                {'b': 0.5, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02},
                {'b': 1.0, 'x': 1.0, 'm': 0.02}]
    muestras = [d for d in muestras for _ in range(10)]

    simulaciones = 10

    estadisticas = {jugador:{s:{muestra:{senal:[0 for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos)+1)]
                        for senal in senales}
                            for muestra in range(len(muestras))}
                                for s in range(len(sm))}
                                    for jugador in jugadores}


    for su in range(len(sm)):
        for mu in range(len(muestras)):
            for _ in range(simulaciones):
                juego = Partida(jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, sm[su]['s1'], sm[su]['s2'],sm[su]['s3'],sm[su]['s4'], muestras[mu]['b'],muestras[mu]['x'], muestras[mu]['m'])
                juego.jugar()
                for n, ronda in enumerate(juego.memoria):
                    for jugador, senal in ronda.items():
                        estadisticas[jugador][su][mu][senal][n] += 1

        with open('practica2.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
            writer =csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';',
                        quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            writer.writerow(['Muestra', 'Jugador', 'Ronda', 'Patron','s1','s2','s3','s4', 'b', 'x', 'm'] + senales)

            for jugador in jugadores:
                for su in range(len(sm)):
                    for mu in range(len(muestras)):
                        for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos)+1):
                            aux = [estadisticas[jugador][su][mu][senal][ronda-1] for senal in senales]
                            writer.writerow([mu+1, jugador, ronda, patron, sm[su]['s1'], sm[su]['s2'],sm[su]['s3'],sm[su]['s4'], muestras[mu]['b'], muestras[mu]['x'], muestras[mu]['m']]+aux)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Me gustaría saber si estas implementaciones que he realizado en el código son correctas.

**Edición:**

Adicionalmente, lo que ya me resulta más complicado pensar cómo solucionar, imaginemos que queremos obtener los resultados del juego (nuestro juego ahora permite obtener x muestras de x simulaciones para cada combinación de parámetros deseada) para dos patrones diferentes en el orden de emparejamientos. Por ejemplo, un patrón A de emparejamientos con un patrón B de emparejamientos:

```
patronA_emparejamientos =[[(1, 2), (3, 4)],
                         [(1, 3), (2, 4)],
                         [(1, 4), (2, 3)]]

patronB_emparejamientos =[[(1, 3), (2, 4)],
                         [(1, 4), (2, 3)],
                         [(1, 2), (3, 4)]]
```

Esto ahora podemos hacerlo con nuestro programa realizando 2 simulaciones independientemente, una para el tipo de emparejamientos A y otra para el tipo de emparejamientos B, y luego combinando los archivos csv. Pero no deja de resultar farragoso.

¿Alguna idea para que el programa nos de la posibilidad de obtener en el mismo archivo csv los resultados de ambos patrones de emparejamiento?